# Firebase crashes app with iOS 10 on launch

Tags: ios, firebase

Recently find out that Firebase crashes an application on iOS 10.2 simulator platform. All recipes I've found about that I've tried, no resolution. What I did: cleaned "Derived data" folder and restarted Xcode and simulator, set "Use safe area layout guide" (that time I didn't know yet that firebase causing the crash), updated firebase pods to latest version (cleaned and rebuilt project as well). All these above didn't fix an issue. What state is currently - firebase SDK versions:

```
Using Firebase (4.8.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.5)
Using FirebaseAuth (4.4.1)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.13)
Using FirebaseDatabase (4.1.3)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.8)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.12)
Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.27.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.3)
Using TPInAppReceipt (1.2)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
```

Exception is caused with 'Firebase.configure()' line.
Using Swift4, Xcode 9.

Exception description in log:

```
__nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash unavailable "libsystem_network.dylib: nw_host_stats_add_src :: received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument"
```

One more detail: 'firebase --version' in the Terminal gives 3.9.1 version, I'm not sure it's revenant, but why can be that and does it correspond to my question?

I can't find any tips to resolve this exception. Those I've found either not revenant or didn't help. What can raise this issue and what could be suggestion to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: comment "Firebase.configure()" and run again to make sure this caused due to Firebase.

Comment: I've did that. Actually, there are two modules, causing exceptions: Firebase and AdMob. If I comment both of them, there aren't exceptions, uncommenting any of them gives exactly the same exception

Comment: Some ideas at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48959

Comment: Nothing of them helped me. Sent request to Firebase support